# past perfect vs past simple, value of meaning holds true today

Tags: past-perfect

I took this from Google. The PAST PERFECT TENSE indicates that an action was completed (finished or "perfected") at some point in the past before something else happened.

An event takes place sometime in the past. What was said, still holds true today, so I want to say, I agree in the present tense.

The past simple seems to me a better option but the past perfect holds true so far as the event, ie, "the friend saying something" was in the past, the time is non specific, ie, recently.

Recently I had visited a friend, as I left, he had remarked that..blah. I agree with him.

Recently i visited a friend, as I left, he remarked...blah. I agree with him.

Are they both possibly correct or is one better? I am also unsure if I need to say, I agreed with him!
Thanks for any advice.
Richard

Comment: Past is normally used. Past perfect is for special cases where you want to emphasize the relative priority of events.

Comment: Think about it this way: when you say "I **had** visited a friend", that means it happened before some other event in the past.  What is the other event that happened in the past?  There isn't really one, so the simple past is better.